# Summable and Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm just trying to write a proof here and can't seem to find a definition for this, but if we have some nonnegative sequence ${a_n}$ which is summable, is the fact that the partial sum is convergent trivial or does work have to be done in proving it?

Answer (score 1):

If $s_n$ denotes the partial sum then it is monotone non-decreasing (since $a_n\geq0)$ and bounded (since the sequence is summable). This results in convergence to its (finite) least upper bound. If for instance $x$ is smaller than this least upper bound then $s_n>x$ if $n$ is large enough. Next to that $s_n$ will not be larger then its least upper bound and this all amounts in convergence to its least upper bound.

Comment: Can we show that the sequence $s_n$ is bounded if all we know is that the sequence $a_n$ is summable?

Comment: By *summable* you mean $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}<\infty$ right? Notice
that in that case $0\leq s_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}\leq\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}<\infty$
for each $n$.

Comment: Ah, that's it. Thanks.